# Making a slider cycle automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

My javascript is pretty basic and I'm looking for a nudge in the right direction

I've just made a simple slider which works great when clicked.  But I've now been asked to make it cycle through the slides automatically.

Can you suggest what sort of functions I should be looking at?

I've put a work copy of my code on codepen here:
http://codepen.io/DeadWhisky/pen/kvytH

And here's the javascript:

```
$("#kickstart").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("slider-ul").style.top="0px";
    document.getElementById("slider-nav").style.background="url(http://dev.learningpeople.co.uk/imgs/entry-it/slider-nav.png) repeat-y 0 -201px";
});

$("#support").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("slider-ul").style.top="-160px";
    document.getElementById("slider-nav").style.background="url(http://dev.learningpeople.co.uk/imgs/entry-it/slider-nav.png) repeat-y 0 -161px";        
});

$("#security").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("slider-ul").style.top="-320px";
    document.getElementById("slider-nav").style.background="url(http://dev.learningpeople.co.uk/imgs/entry-it/slider-nav.png) repeat-y 0 -121px";
});

$("#network").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("slider-ul").style.top="-480px";
    document.getElementById("slider-nav").style.background="url(http://dev.learningpeople.co.uk/imgs/entry-it/slider-nav.png) repeat-y 0 -81px";        
});

$("#slider-nav li").click(function() {
    $("#slider-nav li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: I'm getting there slowly here's the latest version http://codepen.io/DeadWhisky/pen/vaGng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use setInterval() and calculate the position

```
    var moveAmm = 0;
    var bgAmm = 201;
    var slideInterval = setInterval(function () {
        moveAmm < 480 ? moveAmm += 160 : moveAmm = 0;
        bgAmm == 81 ? bgAmm = 201 : bgAmm -= 40;
        $('#slider-ul').css('top', '-' + moveAmm + "px");
        $('#slider-nav').css('background', 'url(http://dev.learningpeople.co.uk/imgs/entry-it/slider-nav.png) repeat-y 0 -' + bgAmm + 'px');
    }, 3000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VnmcE/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` to make a function run every so many milliseconds. This function can move to the next slide. Note that this will affect your `.click` functions slightly, as they may be clicked at the same time the interval is auto-switching slides.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tevbj/)

```
var top = -320;
var offset = -121;
var nextSibling;
setInterval(function () {
    autoSlide();
}, 3000);

function autoSlide() {
    if (top == -480) {
        top = 0;
        offset = -201;
        nextSibling = $("#slider-nav li:first");
    } else {
        top -= 160;
        offset += 40;
        nextSibling = $(".selected").next("li");
    }
    document.getElementById("slider-ul").style.top = top + "px";
    document.getElementById("slider-nav").style.background = "url(http://dev.learningpeople.co.uk/imgs/entry-it/slider-nav.png) repeat-y 0 " + offset + "px";
    $("#slider-nav li").removeClass("selected");
    nextSibling.addClass("selected");
}
```